# Non-static class get the data across other classes

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to C# so go easy on me.
I have a class UserData.

```
    public class UserData
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Token { get; set; }
        public string ConversationID { get; set; }
    }
```

And instantiate it in my main class.

```
public class Main {
 var userDataObjects = new UserData();
 userDataObjects.UserId = 5;
 userDataObjects.Token = "sampleXh123xczx";
 userDataObjects.ConversationID = "2";
 protected DialogsTurn _GetDialog;

 public main(){
  _GetDialog = new DiagsTurn();
 }
    public override async Task OnTurnAsync()
    {
    await _GetDialog.GetNextDialog();
    }

}
```

```
    public class DialogsTurn : Controller
    {
        private readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        private const string BASE_URL = "https://sample.net";

        var userDataObjects = new UserData();
        public async Task GetNextDialog()
        {
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(
                HttpMethod.Get,
                $"{BASE_URL}/api/Dialogs/GetNextDialog?Id={userDataObjects.UserId}");

            request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", userDataObjects.Token);

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(body).result;
                UserDataExtractedDto.DialogTurnID = result.dialogId;
            }
    }
```

And once it was instantiated I need to call it from other classes.
Let's say in my DialogSTurn class I have a GetNextDialog method and I need the Token and UserId. I know I can that data as a parameter. But it's not the case for my application that I built.

Comment: public class void turnDialog() is not valid. Provide a working sample of what you want done.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you need to do here

Comment: Is `UserId`, `Token` and `ConversationID` constant everywhere or it will change as per instantiation of  `UserData`?

Comment: I Edited my questions.

Comment: You can easily pass your UserData object into your methods, just create another constructor that takes the needed objects.

Comment: Yea2, that makes sense. I got it working.